# Specific folder won't cut and paste to new location in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I wanted to move the OneDrive folder from the Windows C drive to a second SSD (E) on the same PC.
So I "unlinked" my OneDrive and tried to cut/paste from the C-drive to the E-drive.
Some folders were moved but there are three that remains.
I have admin priviliges for each folder, and there are no error-messages.
I try to move the reamining folders using CTRL+X and CTRL+V or via the explorer menu from right-clicking the folders, but they won't react to my command. The problem persist only with these specific folders.

How can I solve this problem ? What is going on ?

Comment: When you say unlinked, did you do so from the OneDrive application itself? If so, copy those folders to the new location, redo OneDrive application setup, choosing to customize the setup so you can set the new folder as the OneDrive directory, approve the error message stating there are existing data there, then go back and delete the old OneDrive folder _(if it doesn't allow doing so, reboot and then it should)_

Comment: Yes I unlinked from the OneDrive settings.
With OneDrive not signed in, I try to cut and paste the subfolders from the old OneDrive folder to a new folder on a different drive. The majority of the folders would move to the new location, but three folders remain. These won't react to the normal cut/paste procedure

Comment: Have these folders remained completely unmoved, or most of their files were moved?

Comment: For these folders, no files are moved

Comment: Anything special about them, such as permissions? Are they being used by some program(s)? Can you [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1631305/edit) a screenshot of them?

Comment: I have full permissions to these folders. There is nothing special about them. I can move them into a different folder on the C drive, and I can move other folders from the C drive to the target folder on the E drive.

Comment: There is something special about them, you just have to find out what. But as you like.

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk Can you _copy_ and paste them into the new folder (not cut)? If no, they're likely online only files and aren't store locally (e.g. they're placeholder files) and the file attributes would indicate this. To find the specific reason why they're not being moved, use either `robocopy` or `xcopy`.

Comment: If you haven't run **OneDrive** setup to create the **OneDrive** folder on `E:\ `, those unmoveable folders are probably still somehow flagged as System folders.